# Toggle spoiler with div instead of spoiler button

Tags: html, css

I really like the (simple) spoiler that's described in this page: http://www.bloggersentral.com/2013/03/content-spoiler-with-simple-css3.html.

It works via a *spoiler button* that can be clicked on to display content in a div ('content div'), and thereafter it can be clicked on to hide content in that 'content div'.

However, I would really like it when I can click on a *div* instead of the *spoiler button* to show and hide content in the 'content div'.

I've never used input class or type before, can you help me? Or put me in the right directions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not place the onclick event handler on the div you want to use, and remove the button code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function for showing the content you can call functions like this:

`<div onclick="myspoilerfunction()">Click me to spoiler</div>`

Source [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp)